# Nodemon not restarting NodeJS server in Docker

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, docker-volume, nodemon

I'm trying to dockerize a NodeJS Express server with Typescript and I can't make nodemon restart my app on changes. I have found several other questions about this problem on StackOverflow, but none of them really helped me. I believe that something in my configuration is wrong.

`package.json`

```json
{
    "name": "backend",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "tsc -p .",
        "dev:ts": "tsc -w",
        "dev:js": "nodemon --legacy-watch --watch ./src --watch ./app/src dist/index.js",
        "dev": "concurrently npm:dev:*",
        "start": "node dist/index.js"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "alessandrofoglia07",
    "license": "MIT",
    "dependencies": {
        "bcrypt": "^5.1.0",
        "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.12",
        "cors": "^2.8.5",
        "curse-filter": "^3.1.0",
        "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
        "express": "^4.18.2",
        "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.1",
        "mongoose": "^7.4.1",
        "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
        "node-cron": "^3.0.2",
        "nodemailer": "^6.9.4",
        "uuid": "^9.0.0",
        "zod": "^3.21.4"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
        "@types/cors": "^2.8.13",
        "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
        "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
        "@types/leo-profanity": "^1.5.0",
        "@types/multer": "^1.4.7",
        "@types/node-cron": "^3.0.8",
        "@types/nodemailer": "^6.4.9",
        "@types/uuid": "^9.0.2",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.2.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.2.0",
        "concurrently": "^8.2.0",
        "eslint": "^8.45.0",
        "nodemon": "^3.0.1",
        "typescript": "^5.1.6"
    },
    "type": "module"
}
```

`tsconfig.json`

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2016",
        "module": "ESNext",
        "rootDir": "./src",
        "moduleResolution": "NodeNext",
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "strict": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true
    }
}
```

`Dockerfile.dev`

```
FROM node:18
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
ENV PORT 5000
ENV NODE_ENV development
EXPOSE $PORT
CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
    frontend:
        container_name: luxedge-frontend
        tty: true
        stdin_open: true
        env_file:
            - ./frontend/.env
    backend:
        container_name: luxedge-backend
        tty: true
        stdin_open: true
        env_file:
            - ./backend/.env
        ports:
            - '5000:5000'
```

`docker-compose-dev.yml`

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
    frontend:
        build:
            context: ./frontend
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
        ports:
            - '3000:3000'
        volumes:
            - ./frontend/src:/app/src:ro
            - ./frontend/public:/app/public:ro
            - ./frontend/index.html:/app/index.html:ro
    backend:
        restart: always
        build:
            context: ./backend
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
        volumes:
            - ./backend/src:/app/src:ro
            - ./backend/public:/app/public:ro
            - /app/node_modules
        environment:
            - NODE_ENV=development
            - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
```

The command I am using for starting the frontend and backend containers

```bash
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose-dev.yml up -d
```

I am using Docker desktop on Windows x64 with WSL2.

Answer (score 0):

Because the file system of **Windows** is different than that of containers. Docker containers are native to **Linux** systems, so file-system events (i.e. file change event, file delete event etc.) are not recognized by the host (Windows) machine.

If you copy your project inside the *WSL2* system (Ubuntu / Debian / whatever distro you're using), then it will work. Now the file system of the container will match with the host (WSL) system.

I have written [an article on LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/why-you-should-consider-moving-away-from-docker-desktop-mahmud-sazzad) a while ago in this topic. You can check that out for further reading.

Comment: Shouldn't the --legacy-watch flag in nodemon command enable restarting the application on every fs change event either from a windows with wsl machine or a container's native linux system?

Comment: According to my experience, it's a "hit-or-miss" issue. Either it will work, or it won't. And sometimes I can't even find out why it doesn't work. So I didn't bother and transferred all my projects to my *Debian* system running on WSL2.